# "DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a profanity discord bot. Whenever I run it, it is fine but when I type a word that it's supposed to filter out, it stops. This is the error I get when typing in a blocked word.

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\loser\Desktop\word filter bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\loser\Desktop\word filter bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
at async TextChannel.send (C:\Users\loser\Desktop\word filter bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:175:15)
at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\loser\Desktop\word filter bot\index.js:33:19) {
method: 'post',
path: '/channels/954840804466257921/messages',
code: 50006,
httpStatus: 400,
requestData: {
json: {
  content: undefined,
  tts: false,
  nonce: undefined,
  embeds: undefined,
  components: undefined,
  username: undefined,
  avatar_url: undefined,
  allowed_mentions: undefined,
  flags: undefined,
  message_reference: undefined,
  attachments: undefined,
  sticker_ids: undefined
  },
  files: []
  }
  }
```

and here is my code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });
const prefix = '-'

client.once('ready', () => {
console.log('woohoo, Im ready to get online and block some words!')
client.user.setActivity('-help', {type: 'LISTENING'})
})

client.on('message', async message => {
if(message.channel.type === 'dm' || message.author.bot) return;

const logChannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '954845946326450206')
let words = ["banana", "orange"]

let foundInText = false;
for (var i in words) {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(words[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText = true;
}

if (foundInText) {
    let logEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}> Said a bad word`)
    .addField('The Message', message.content)
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setTimestamp()
    logChannel.send(logEmbed)

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`That word is not allowed here`)
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setTimestamp()
    let msg = await message.channel.send(embed);
    message.delete()
    msg.delete({timeout: '3500'})
}
})
```

is there anyway you guys can help me out? I would really like to get this up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using discord.js v13.

The `send` method only take one parameter since v13. You can to use `send({ embeds: [your, cool, embeds] });` to send embeds or any message that contain not only contents.

Also the `Message.prototype.delete()` does not take any parameter now. You have to use `setTimeout` if you want to delete messages after a certain amount of time.

Comment: How would I check my discord.js version?

Comment: WAIT idk if this will work for forever but I just downgraded to discord.js v12. so for now i'll use v12.

Comment: @CryoBeast382_YT In your terminal, use `npm ls discord.js`, or check your package.json. Discord.js v12 will stop working soon so i recommend you learn v13.